# ORDER BY in SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by

I want to display result in a list view ordered descending in terms of date. I'm querying like:

```
db.query(boolean....where second last is order by)
```

But when I put `KEY_DATE+"DESC"` my app crashes. I even tried storing this in a string and then entering it with no luck.

Comment: add space between `KEY_DATE+" DESC"`, I this can be a problem or post us some stack trace.

Comment: @Sarz thats the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your query, It should be like:

```
KEY_DATE+" DESC"
```

**Best Practice:** Whenever you are querying your Database also print on console to verify and cross check, you should know the basic SQL as well.

Comment: I got it to work. Its funny that it was just the "space". I'm actually using AIDE and I'm not sure whether it has a console or not. Also I'm more of a super new developer, so I'm just getting started with all this. Thanks.

Comment: Here we say thanks by accepting an answer :), And no worries bro m always glad to help (as best as I can)